# How to change the view displayed at the beginning in Yii?

Tags: php, view, yii

By default, class Controller has:

```
public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

This view should not be displayed as the first client, I need to display at site/index was loaded single-column view, but the links from this page used layouts/column2.
In other words, the user sees visiting the website:

[image: 1 column]

Clicks on the menu and it has a two-column displays the site:

[image: 2 column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the used layout on a view basis:

```
function actionIndex() {
    $this->layout = '//layouts/column1';
}

function actionSomethingElse() {
    $this->layout = '//layouts/column2'; // If the default layout is column2 you can skip this line
}
```

Comment: Just found the answer. Thanks answered and attended to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

In siteController.php

```
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';
```

In action:

```
    public $layout='//layouts/column1';
    $this->render('index');
```